# Summation within iteration over two variables with matrix operations

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, optimization

I have the following matrices: Q, P, q and y with shapes (100,100), (100,100), (100,100) and (100,2) respectively.

For every i, I want to compute the following:
[image]

This is what I've tried so far, it appears to work but I know this is bad practice
and painfully slow.

```
grad = np.zeros(100, 2)
for i in range(100):
    tmp = 0
    for j in range(100):
         tmp += ((P[i, j] - Q[i, j]) * q[i, j] * (y[i, :] - y[j, :]))
    grad[i, :] = tmp * 4
```

My question is how can I compute this using matrix operations instead of nested loops?

Comment: The equation in the image is not a double summation, but a single sum over j. The result would then have i as a variable. So would you like an answer for a double sum, or for the equation in the image?

Comment: @tom10 You are correct, I did not present my question properly. For every I i want to compute the summation, so it should not be double summation,  but rather summation within iteration. 

Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your notation, try broadcasting:

```
grad = 4 * (((P-Q)*q)[...,None]*(y[:,None,:]-y[None])).sum(axis=1)
```